# How to encrypt a directory so that it could be decrypted from Mac, Windows, and GNU/Linux

Tags: encryption

How to encrypt a directory so that it could be decrypted from Mac, Windows, and GNU/Linux? Preferably it could be used as a regular folder while ulocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file encryption software that work multi-platform and allows direct read/write access to the decrypted files is [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr).

Also multi-platform but without the ability to allow direct read/write access to the decrypted files AES encrypted ZIP file. You can e.g. use 7-Zip to create and update the files. The `.7z` archive format is also a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

My software https://github.com/netheril96/securefs can do this. It has the benefit over VeraCrypt that you do not need to set a fixed size beforehand.